# Split string items

Tags: iphone

I have a string called aux which hold six url images, I want to split those images and display it in UIImage view the images are like

```
http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/cassini_titan_15.jpg
http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/cassini_titan_15.jpg
http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/cassini_titan_15.jpg
http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/cassini_titan_15.jpg
http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/cassini_titan_15.jpg
http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/cassini_titan_15.jpg
```

I want to split these images using if condition and display it in image-view.

Comment: Those are all the same string, and you do not say how they are stored? CSV String? NSArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read those lines from file where they one by one in separate rows, than you can try this:

```
NSString *urlsList = ... // your list in first post each url on it's line
NSArray *imagesURL = [urlsList componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: "your list in first post each url on it's line" means?

Comment: how to set this in if condition to split those images

Comment: Hm, okay, maybe I don't understand what you want. Why you need to use **if** to split those list of urls? I gave you an examp,e how you can retrieve array of urls if source data was stored in file or just all urls stored on new line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952229/splitting-image-url please check this url.Thanks

Comment: Ok, I've tried to give some answer in that topic.

Comment: ,its works fine,Thnk you very much

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to determine what string is separating them.  If you have that, you can just use the `-[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:]` method.  For example:

```
//This assumes they are separated with a comma
NSString *imageString = @"http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/cassini_titan_15.jpg,http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/cassini_titan_16.jpg";
NSArray *images = [imageString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

// Now you have each image as an element on the images array
```

Comment: if ([images objectAtIndex:0]) {
   NSURL *url = [NSURL 
        URLWithString:aux];
   
   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
   UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]; 
   [_homeImage setImage:image];
  }
  else if ([images objectAtIndex:1{…...

Comment: is this code right?i am not getting any values