# Nothing displayed after splitting a list of image URLs

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, nsdata, nsurl

I have six image URLs in a string named `aux`. I split it with component separated by newlines. I want to pick images one by one from `aux` and display each in an `ImageView`. My code is:

```
aux = [_homeText.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@  ",item.shortDescription]];
[_homeText setText:aux];  
NSString *list =aux;
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
[listItems count];
if ([listItems objectAtIndex:0]) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:aux];
            /*UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"hai" message:aux delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];*/          
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]; 
        [_homeImage setImage:image];
}
else if ([listItems objectAtIndex:1])
{
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:aux];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]; 
            [_homeImage setImage:image];
}
```

There is no error but I get no image. Why? How do I fix this?

Comment: @Vladimir any solution for my problem

Comment: try to debug your code and check what values do you actually get in your strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both **data** and **image** not *nil*, you may try to correctly initialize _homeImage.
I don'w know why, but I think what you created _*homeImage* like this:

`_homeImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];`

Try to do something like this:

```
CGSize imageSize = [image size];
[_homeImage setFrame:CGRectMake([_homeImage frame].origin.x, 
                                [_homeImage frame].origin.y, 
                                imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];
[_homeImage setImage:image];
[image release], image = nil;
```

Comment: Are you getting correct URLs and all data loaded? Ensure what you added this imageView (I think you done this) as subview somewhere. But it's really strange, I can't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Can you show what data stored in **listItems**? And I don't understand what was added by this: `aux = [_homeText.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@  ",item.shortDescription]];
    [_homeText setText:aux];` to that _aux_ string.

Comment: I've already show how to split lines by new line characters. Can you tell how much elements inside _listItems_?

Comment: i know how to split newline elements as u mentioned earlier,but how to get thoes elements and display it in imageview

Comment: Oh my God, sorry, I just noticed what is wrong. You try to use whole bunch of URLS in `NSURL *url = [NSURL  URLWithString:aux];`. You should use `NSURL *url = [NSURL  URLWithString:[listItems objectAtIndex:0]];` instead. To display all six images at once, you'll need 6 different imageViews and iterate over array with URLs for images.

Comment: I alert the list ,list holds the 6 image urls.

Comment: If you mean code which was commented, than yes, it will. Did you tried place this code `*url = [NSURL URLWithString:[listItems objectAtIndex:0]];` instead of `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:aux];` (this is for if object at index 0 exists, for other case replace 0 with 1). Please, check my code.